# My unless statement doesn't respond to == 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to display a button only when invitation_limit for the current user is nil or something. For "0" it shouldn't be displayed.

I'm trying the following in my view:

```
<% unless current_user.invitation_limit == 0 %>
  <div class="card-action">
    <%= link_to new_user_invitation_path do %>
      <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light black darken-2">Invite</button>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But now my button is displayed it doesn't work: no errors, but always the button, even when invitation_limit is "0".

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried printing the value to see if it's actually 0?
Another thing I can think of, do you need @ in front of current_user?

Good luck!

Comment: Ai, spot on! When I print it, it returns 5 instead of 0. There seems to be a global value which is set to 5 in an initializer that overrules my other data... Thanks!